# Simplify $4(ab+cd)^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Resolve $4(ab+cd)^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)^2$ into four factors.

$\Rightarrow 4a^2b^2+8abcd+4c^2d^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)^2 $

$\Rightarrow (2ab+2cd)^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)^2 $

$\Rightarrow (2ab+2cd+a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)(2ab+2cd-a^2-b^2+c^2+d^2) $

Then I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Hint: $\;2ab+2cd+a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2 = (a^2+2ab+b^2) - (c^2 - 2cd + d^2)$

Comment: Probably need to make repeated use of the identity $~(r^2 - s^2) = (r-s) \times (r+s).$

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: CAS helps [sometime](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Factor%5B4%28ab%2Bcd%29%5E2-%28a%5E2%2Bb%5E2-c%5E2-d%5E2%29%5E2%5D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(2ab+2cd+a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)(2ab+2cd-a^2-b^2+c^2+d^2)$$
$$=(a^2+b^2+2ab-(c^2+d^2-2cd))(c^2+d^2+2cd-(a^2+b^2-2ab))$$
$$=((a+b)^2-(c-d)^2)((c+d)^2-(a-b)^2)$$
$$=(a+b+c-d)(a+b-c+d)(a-b+c+d)(-a+b+c+d)$$